# Extract graphic images from FLAC audio files

Tags: audio, extract, flac, album-art

I bought some music online and downloaded it in FLAC format, and I was pleasantly surprised to see some artwork apparently embedded into each audio file.  I suspect that they're a bit higher resolution than Windows' "Extra large icons" preview, so is there a way to extract them into their own files?

Basically the reverse of this:
[Embed album art image to FLAC file with ffmpeg](https://superuser.com/q/843914/405089)

Comment: I use MP3Nity to do this...Best tag software ever coded, worth every penny x2, use the trial software to be sure it meets your needs before purchase, free upgrades for life......http://www.littlelan.com/mp3nity/

Comment: @Moab: Okay, it's been a few days and no one else has said anything.  I've installed mp3nity, but can't figure out how to extract a graphical image from FLAC to a standalone image file.  Do you think you could post an answer to that effect?  Thanks!

Comment: When you open MP3Nity and have the directory open and flac files "selected", look in the lower right pane and select "Picture" button, then you can export them or add a new image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some more googling, and apparently this topic is more sensitive than most about getting your search terms right.  A search for `extract artwork from flac` turned up this, though still indirectly:

https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/EasyTAG

[image]

I found a few others by the same search, but I really like this one because it doesn't try to make you guess the embedded image size and then rescale to that.  Instead, it not only shows you what's *actually* there, but as far as I can tell, it *must* save the embedded data unmodified, which is exactly what I want.  (If you do want something different, you can use a standalone image editor from there.)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is still on the topic, but I first found this thread while searching info on the same task, and than found another easy and free solution: the [foobar2000](https://www.foobar2000.org/download) media player, which, AFAIK, manages .flac out of the box, allows exporting embedded artwork.

1. Rightclick the track
2. "Tagging"
3. "Manage attached pictures"
4. A dialog box appears
5. Select the pictures you wish to have exported
6. Click "Export"

Works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Run `ffprobe example.flac` to locate the “video” track. (It’s most likely `0:1`.) With that, you can extract the image:

```
ffmpeg -i example.flac -map 0:1 cover.jpg
```